# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions (firebase and admob)

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am in troubled because:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
>                                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
>                                                                              at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4912)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4518)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4458)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Show us your gradles(app.gradle and project.gradle) please

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you are using google play-service dependency in your project.

Just downgrade the google play-service dependency to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` and the problem may get solved.